# SQL Server XML add attribute if non-existent

Tags: sql, xml, xpath, xquery, xquery-sql

I am trying to add an attribute if it does not exist. It should be simple, but I am new to XML XPath/XQuery/etc., so excuse my ignorance.

I want to be able to pass XML data and modify it...

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[ConvertXmlData](@xmlData XML)
RETURNS XML
AS
BEGIN
  RETURN @xmlData.<something here>
END
```

If I pass data like:

```
<something> 
   this is sample data <xxx id="1"/> and <xxx id="2" runat="server" />. More <yyy id="3" />
</something>
```

I would like

```
<something>
this is sample data <xxx id="1" runat="server" /> and <xxx id="2" runat="server" />. More <yyy id="3" />

</something>
```

And not :

```
<something>
this is sample data <xxx id="1" runat="server" /> and <xxx id="2" runat="server" runat="server"/>. More <yyy id="3" />
</something>
```

Comment: SQL 2008 R2, fyi, if that helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do

```
SET @xmlData.modify('insert attribute runat { "server" } into descendant::xxx[not(@runat)][1]');
```

This will however only change the first `xxx` descendant not having a runat attribute, at least with SQL Server 2005 you can only modify one node at a time.

Maybe combining the above with a WHILE helps e.g.

```
WHILE @xmlData.exist('descendant::xxx[not(@runat)]') = 1
BEGIN
  SET @xmlData.modify('insert attribute runat { "server" } into descendant::xxx[not(@runat)][1]');
END
```

I don't have access to SQL Server 2008 R2 but I think the modify is still limited to one node at a time so you could try

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[ConvertXmlData](@xmlData XML)
RETURNS XML
AS
BEGIN
    WHILE @xmlData.exist('descendant::xxx[not(@runat)]') = 1
    BEGIN
      SET @xmlData.modify('insert attribute runat { "server" } into descendant::xxx[not(@runat)][1]');
    END
  RETURN @xmlData
END
```